# How to use on RadMaskedTextBox to accept many format of phone numbers

Tags: telerik, telerik-radmaskedtextbox

I try to use a RadMaskedTextBox in an Web application (ASP.NET) for my company. I'd like to use several masks in order to accept many phone numbers format. The component must accept phone numbers with these separators : "-", "/", "|" and space between figures. Here are some example of format that i mean:

1- xx-xx-xx-xx-xx 2- xx - xx - xx - xx - xx 3- xx.xx.xx.xx.xx 4- xx/xx/xx/xx/xx 5- xx / xx / xx / xx 6- xx|xx|xx|xx|xx 7- xx | xx | xx | xx

Evidently, the component needs to accept figures only.

Can anybody help me, please ? I'm looking for a solution for a couple of days.

Thank You.

Comment: It's not clear. What are you try to achieve ? One text box with multiple masked that switch when the user type trying to find the right pattern ? Why not display one of those patern and  let the user use it. It will make no change for them as they will just input numbers..

Comment: i'm sorry if i'm not clear. I have a radMaskedTextBox that will allow users to add phone numbers. I would like people copy-paste all format they want. I've already quoted the format that the component needs to accept. How can i do ?. I tried to get the value which the user wants to copy-paste in javascript but i can't. Everytime i got the value after being handle by the default mask. it might be truncated.

Comment: I see what you want and i don't know if a Masked can do that. But what about a simple text box with a RegExp validation ?  and extract the number in code behind. Did you user comes up with this Idea ? Did some one really ask to copy past a phone using `|` as delimiter ?

Comment: " I tried to get the value which the user wants to copy-paste in javascript but i can't. " did you wanted to catch copy pasta on the fly in js. And process it to make it look like keyboard input so the maskedText box will register only the right input and ignore anything else ..

Comment: "Make a copy past look like user input in Js" could make a great question.

Comment: Dont try this foolish solution, Do not over think the issue. User have to write a their number: 1rst they know it they dont need to copy past. This will lead to more mistake because they will often miss the last or first digit. Telerik component will never accept mutilple mask because it's not a good idea for the user.

Comment: Hi @PierreLebon,
I've also sent this question to Telerik's Support. They told me that the mask can't handle this case. Maybe it will be later.
I don't have time anymore to work on it. Our team has decided to deploy the component with "." as delimiter. 
Your solution seems to be good but my case needs to be handled by telerik component only. That's why i use the RadMaskedTextBox of Telerik. As soon as i 'll have more times, i'll try your solution. 
I'll keep you informed about the result. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @PierreLebon,
I've also sent this question to Telerik's Support. They told me that the mask can't handle this case. Maybe it will be later.
I don't have time anymore to work on it. Our team has decided to deploy the component with "." as delimiter. 
Your solution seems to be good but my case needs to be handled by telerik component only. That's why i use the RadMaskedTextBox of Telerik. As soon as i 'll have more times, i'll try your solution. 
I'll keep you informed about the result. Thanks.

Comment: Application should normalise and 'educate' user. They will win more time learning a standard input. The `.` is a great choice. Simple and classic input should be the more strict and basic. "Keep it simple, stupid" especially with telerik control or your web site wil be so slow

Comment: Yes you're right. They have to write first but they also need that the system allow them to copy-paste. In reality, in 80% they do a copy-paste because it's usefull and practical for their activities.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but it's very difficult to educate these users. They demand and we execute, unfortunately. That's what happening in this company. We must adapt.
Thank you for your help. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: x.value.split(/[\\\+\-\.\s\_\/\*,;:]/g).join("").match(/.{1,2}/g).join(".");
Cut the match-join if needed. Yeah we must adapt.